# Menubar dropdown context

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown, menubar

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
    body, html {
        height: 100%;
    }
    .parallax {
        background-image: url('../images/firstpage.jpg');
        height: 100%; 
        margin: 0;
        /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
        background-attachment: fixed;
     
        background-position: center;
     
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
     
        background-size: cover;
    }
    button{
     background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,255,255,0));
        border: none;
     font-family: "Roboto";
     color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 26px;
     z-index: 1;
     float: left;
    }
    .fixed{
     position: fixed;
    }
    .textbackground
    {
     position: absolute;
     left: 100px;
     top: 150px;
    }
    .textbackgroundbar{
     overflow: hidden;
     width: 800px;
     height: 50px;
     background: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(255,255,255,30), rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,255,255,30));
    }
    .dropbtn {
        display: block;
        color: black;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 24px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
   }
    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
     position: absolute;
     background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.3),rgba(0,0,0,0.1));
     min-width: 800px;
     min-height: 700px;
        overflow: auto;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .dropdown-content a {
        color: red;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
    .show {display:block;}
    .dropdown-content1 {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content1 {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
   <div class="textbackground">
        <div class="textbackgroundbar">
       <div class="dropdown">
             <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
       <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown2</button>
        </div>
  </div>
     <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
           <a href="#home">Home</a>
           <a href="#about">About</a>
           <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
     </div>
         
     <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#home">Home2</a>
        <a href="#about">About2</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact2</a>
     </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

What is the problem here? It should dropdown 2 different things when i click the specific button .. but it doesn't.
If i click dropdown it shows home about contact. If i click dropdown 2, same home about contact, but i want it to be home2 about2 contact2.
The entire website contains 5 parallax slides. It is a project for school, to obtain some sort of license, so i'm really trying to understand that code ( and mostly i do ). I understand every "function" but when i combine them all... i just screw up.
So, please, be as clear as you can. Thank you !
P.S: Excuse my bad english, it's not my first language.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same ID for two different div elements.

IDs must be unique.

You may solve this issue simply adding the id text and event object to your inline events:

```
<button onclick="myFunction('myDropdown1', event)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('myDropdown2', event)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown2</button>
```

And so you can change your function in order to handle the parameters.

When clicking on a dropbtn button:

- stop event propagation in order to avoid the window.onclick execution
- hide/remove show class to the dropdown-content div if any
- toggle the show class on the current dropdown-content div

When clicking on the window be sure to be outside the dropdown-content visible div and dropbtn buttons.

For more details take a look to:

> [var elt = element.closest(selectors);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/closest):
>
> The Element.closest() method returns the closest ancestor of the current element (or the current element itself) which matches the selectors given in parameter. If there isn't such an ancestor, it returns null.
>    - >var result = element.matches(selectorString);

The snippet:

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button,
 toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction(eleId, event) {
    //
    // stop event propagation in order to avoid the window.onclick execution
    //
    event.stopPropagation();
    //
    // remove show class to previous shown div
    //
    document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content.show').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
        ele.classList.remove("show");
    });
    //
    // select by id using the param value
    //
    document.getElementById(eleId).classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    //
    // if not a button and not a dropdown-content....
    //
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn') &&  event.target.closest('.dropdown-content') ==  null) {
        //
        // remove show class to previous shown div
        //
        document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content.show').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
            ele.classList.remove("show");
        });
    }
}
```

```css
button{
    background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,255,255,0));
    border: none;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 26px;
    z-index: 1;
    float: left;
}
.fixed{
    position: fixed;
}

.textbackground {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 150px;
}
.textbackgroundbar{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 800px;
    height: 50px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(255,255,255,30), rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,255,255,30));
}

.dropbtn {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.3),rgba(0,0,0,0.1));
    min-width: 800px;
    min-height: 700px;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: red;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.show {display:block;}
.dropdown-content1 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content1 {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
    <div class="textbackground">
        <div class="textbackgroundbar">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="myFunction('myDropdown1', event)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
                <button onclick="myFunction('myDropdown2', event)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown2</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#home">Home2</a>
            <a href="#about">About2</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I would ask another little question. As you can see, if i click on Dropdown it stays open till i click it again, but i want it to close when i click Dropdown2 and open Dropdown2, but it doesn't. If i click Dropdown2, the "textbox" overlaps the other "textbox". What should i do here? If i click outside the menubar, the "textbox" dissapears, how can i make it dissapear when i click dropdown2 too?

Comment: @g0dafk Answer updated, I hope it solves your issues. Let me know.